# Dart WevServer на VPS

Tags: vps

Купил vps на TimeWeb. Поставил туда ubuntu, далее с помощью Dart VM поднял WebServer на 127.0.0.1:8080, соответствующая строка в терминале сообщила, что сервер заработал. Меня интересует как к нему обратиться через браузер. в хроме набираю ip сервера и порт 8080, но ничего не происходит =(

Answer (score 1):

Я не знаю, что такое Dart VM, но настройка "127.0.0.1:8080" означает, что он будет отвечать только на местные запросы (пришедшие с той-же самой машины), ибо 127.0.0.1 -- это обращение к самому себе.

Comment: Получается мне веб сервер подымать на адрес идентичный адресу моего vps сервера?)

Comment: Почитайте документацию. Возможно прокатит что-нибудь типа '0.0.0.0' или '*'

Answer (score 0):

команда

`netstat -anp | grep -i 'listen '`

выведет список процессов (/служб/демонов), с указанием того, кто, на каком адресе и на каком порту слушает подключений. если служба слушает на 127.0.0.1, то подключиться извне к ней не получится.

Comment: Получится изнутри или через прокси или пробросом портов через ССШ ; )))

Answer (score 0):

Тебе надо поднимать веб сервер на дарте на `0.0.0.0:8080`, а не `127.0.0.1:8080`

А обращаться по `айпи твоего сервера:8080` при условии, что у тебя открыт порт 8080

Но вообще это плохие практики:

1. вместо айпи надо завести домен
2. обращаться стоит не напрямую к дарту, а через реверс прокси/балансировщик (nginx, traefik и все такое)
3. тебе нужен TLS сертификат, чтоб было httpS
4. нужно закрыть неиспользуемые порты (например через ufw)
5. вместо Dart VM (скаченного дарт SDK) нужно использовать Dart Runtime - скомпилировав твой сервер в AOT